# Problem training an autoencoder for byte sequence classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am working on a classification task which uses byte sequences as samples. A byte sequence can be normalized as input to neural networks by applying x/255 to each byte x. In this way, I trained a simple MLP and the accuracy is about 80%. Then I trained an autoencoder using 'mse' loss on the whole data to see if it works well for the task. I freezed the weights of the encoder's layers and add a softmax dense layer to it for classification. I retrained the new model (only trained the last layer) and to my surprise, the result was much worse than the MLP, merely 60% accuracy.

Can't the autoencoder learn good features from all the data? Why the result is so bad?

Answer (score 0):

**Possible actions to take:**

- Check the **error** of autoencoder, could it really predict itself?
- **Visualize** the autoencoder results (dimensionality reduction), is the variance explained with fewer dimensions?
- Making model more complex does not necessarily outperform simpler ones, did you plot the validation mse versus epoch? Is there a **global minimum** after a number of steps?
- Do you have enough **epochs**?
- What is the number of **units** you have in your autoencoder? It may be too less (or too much, in case of **underfitting**) depending on the behavior of your data and its volume.
- Did you make any **comparison** with other dimensionality reduction methods like PCA, NMF?
- *Last but not least, is it the best way to engineer your features with autoencoder for this task?*

Answer (score 0):

"Why the result is so bad?" This is not actually a surprise. You've trained one model to be good at compressing the information. The transformations it learns at each layer do not need to be good for any other type of task at all. In fact, it could be throwing away a lot of information that is perfectly helpful for whatever auxiliary classification task you have, but which is not needed for a task purely of compressing and reconstructing the sequence.

Instead of approaching it by training a separate autoencoder, you might have better luck with just adding sparsity penalty terms from the MLP layers into the loss function, or use some other types of regularization like dropout. Finally you could consider more advanced network architectures, like ResNet / ODE layers or Inception layers, modified for a 1D sequence.

Comment: Your advice makes sense, thanks. However, I'm still confused with the application scenarios of autoencoders. When I learn the theory, it is said an AE can be pretrained in an unsupervised fashion to learning interesting features. Then a new network can be created reusing the lower layers to train a classifier. Is it always being restricted in practice like in my task?

Comment: In deep learning literature, there have not been many genuine success stories using autoencoders in the way you mention. Rather instead, the autoencoder is usually combined with an additional type of loss function, usually a GAN that tries to distinguish reconstructions from originals to force the AE to get better across training. One thing the bottleneck layer of an AE can be useful for is a type of embedding model, like creating a nearest neighbor search index or a reverse search index. But usually if you just train an AE, the intermediate layers have no general "goodness" for other tasks.

Comment: Autoencoders are widely regarded as an educational stepping stone to understand deep learning techniques. Maybe they have a few applications or can be extended to solve niche problems, but the field moved on to just considering networks that apply directly to the learning task you care about. You could still have a network architecture in some ways similar to an autoencoder, with a bottleneck layer, but the loss layer would not be merely a reconstruction... instead it would be whatever learning task you're interested in. In the simplest case it would be just like the MLP you started with.